# How does `rake` know where to look for Rakefiles?

Tags: rake

I'm trying to better understand how `rake` works. I've looked on the rake website to see how it works but there isn't a clear explanation for how `rake` searches for Rakefiles and the steps it goes through in resolving dependencies. Can someone explain how `rake` works?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By default `rake` will look for one of these files *under the directory you execute it from*:

- rakefile
- Rakefile
- rakefile.rb
- Rakefile.rb

You can look at Rake's [Application docs](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/Application.html) to see this list

Additionally, any ruby file *including other rakefiles* can be included with a standard Ruby `require` command:

```rb
require 'rake/loaders/external-rakefile'
```

alternatively, you can `import` them:

```rb
import 'rake/loaders/external-rakefile'
```

To make a set of Rake tasks available for use from any directory, create a `.rake` subdirectory within your home directory, and place the appropriate Rake files there. Any rake command with the `-g` option will use these global Rake files (read more [here](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/rake/)):

```rb
rake -g -T
```

Additionally, if `-g` option is set, Rake will first try to load the files form `RAKE_SYSTEM` environment variable, if that is not set, it will default to a `home user directory/.rake/*.rake`. These files will be loaded/imported *in addition* to one of the default files listed above.

Otherwise it will load the first default file (from the above list), and *additionally* import all the rake files from the `rakelib` directory (under location you run `rake` from), OR this directory can be specified using:

```sh
--rakelibdir=RAKELIBDIR or -R RAKELIBDIR: Auto-import any .rake files in RAKELIBDIR. (default is 'rakelib')
```

Comment: Does `rake` look at any environment variables? What is the order of looking up rakefiles? Thanks tolitius!

Comment: @Avry, I added more details about the order and ENV variables to the answer.