# rake command starts running testcases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, testcase

when I run `rake` in `console` its started executing tested cases. How rake is loaded the test cases and execute them?

```
dev@ubuntu:~/Project/test_app (master)$ rake
```

then it started executing test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that `test` is set to default Rake task: see [the code on GinHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake#L4).

That's why `> rake` executes this default task.

Answer (score 0):

By Default when you run Rake, it looks for a rakefile in the current directory (see [How does `rake` know where to look for Rakefiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694967/how-does-rake-know-where-to-look-for-rakefiles))

Then unless you give it a task on the command line it executes the default task which @phts points on in the case of the Rakefile that comes with a default rails app is to run the tests.